# Switched HDD not booting in Lenovo W540

Tags: hard-drive, boot, lenovo-laptop

I got my Seagate Momentus XT 750GB Solid State Hybrid from my other laptop which isn't doing well performance wise and placed it into a new Lenovo W540 but it won't boot into the OS on the HDD when I boot up, the screen is on the lenovo logo for some seconds then it shows me a boot menu, where the Seagate is visible but even when I select it, the same process, black screen then back to boot menu.

Do I have to reinstall Windows onto the HDD? Should I format it? Is this Lenovo not compatible with Solid State Hybrid Drives? Is there some lock in the BIOS

Comment: Windows won't boot if the hardware is very different from what it was originally installed on. As long as the drive wasn't encrypted/password protected you can simply browse and pull data off it using any Linux Live CD/USB, then format it and reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Windows in the Drive required legacy Bios boot and not UEFI boot as set in the new laptop, so I simply changed it in the BIOS settings and it worked like a charm.